# "Ambiguous use of" error in when accessing overloaded function

Tags: swift

I have 3 functions with same name but different signatures defined as following

```
// 1
func send<T: Decodable>(_ request: HTTPSClient.Request) async throws -> T {
...
}

// 2
func send(_ request: HTTPSClient.Request) async throws -> Data {
...
}

// 3
func send(_ request: HTTPSClient.Request) async throws {
...
}
```

Now when trying to call these

```
// Works fine, SomeResponse is Codable
let response: SomeResponse = try await self.send(httpsRequest)

// Works fine
let response: Data = try await self.send(httpsRequest)

// Does not work
try await self.send(httpsRequest)
```

The 1st and 2nd declarations are accessible as expected but on the 3rd one I get error `Ambiguous use of 'send'` with 2nd and 3rd declarations as possible candidates.

According to my understanding this shouldn't happen since the 3rd call does not expect a return so it should call 3rd declaration. What am I missing here?

> Note declaration 2 does not have `@discardableResult`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler what the return type is so change the call to

```
try await self.send(httpsRequest) as Void
```

See [this blog post](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=20) from the Apple Developer site